# If $f,g:X\to[0,\infty]$ is measurable functions, then $f+g$ is measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question about the proof of this problem;

> If $f,g:X\to[0,\infty]$ is measurable functions, then $f+g$ is
> measurable function.

My proof (well known way);

> $\forall a\in\mathbb{R},\  \{f+g>a\}=\cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}(\{f>r\}\cap\{g>a-r\})$. So $\{f+g>a\}$ is measrable set, and $f+g$ is measurable function.

However, in the book I read, the proof was done by doing $\{f=\infty\}, \{g=\infty\}$ separately. Why do we need to separate them? When it is $f(x)=\infty$ and $g(x)=-\infty$, the above proof does not hold, but now that it is $0\leq f(x),g(x)\leq\infty $, it must hold.

Comment: Because you also want to check for the measurability of $\{f+g = \infty\}=\{f=\infty\}\cup\{g=\infty\}$ for they are both non negative. Probably your definition of a measurable function $f$ is that $\{f>a\}$ AND $\{f=\infty\}$ are measurable for all real $a$.

Comment: Isn't $\{f=\infty\}\cup\{g=\infty\}\subset\cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}(\{f>r\}\cap\{g>a-r\})$ satisfied in this case?

Comment: I see your point but I think it depends on your book's/course's notation/assumptions on whether $\{f>a\}$ stands for  $\{x\in X | f(x)\in (a,+\infty)\} or \{x\in X | f(x)\in (a,+\infty]\}$.

Comment: Probably in this book it is $\{f>a\}=\{x\in X:a<f(x)\leq\infty\}$. In the book's proof, it was restricted to $X'=X\backslash(\{f=\infty\}\cup\{g=\infty\})$, and then the proof method above was applied on $X'$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of measurability of the sum of extended-real measurable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581944/proof-of-measurability-of-the-sum-of-extended-real-measurable-functions)

Comment: The problem is the same, but I don't want to know how to prove it, I want to know why my proof is insufficient.